# Grep for values after second pair of brackets

Tags: bash, search, grep, cut

Given a file that looks like this:

```
0,0: (63736)  #F8F8F8  gray(248)
1,0: (63736)  #F8F8F8  gray(248)
2,0: (63736)  #F8F8F8  gray(248)
3,0: (63736)  #F8F8F8  gray(248)
4,0: (63736)  #F8F8F8  gray(248)
5,0: (63736)  #F8F8F8  gray(248)
6,0: (63736)  #F8F8F8  gray(248)
7,0: (63736)  #F8F8F8  gray(248)
8,0: (63736)  #F8F8F8  gray(248)
```

Going all the way to "799,599:". I need the number in between the gray's parenthesis for the line that starts with "590,85:".

The output should be, for example if I wanted the data from "7,0:";

```
248
```

Answer (score 2):

In sed it'd be:

```
$ sed -n 's/^7,0:.*(\([^)]*\).*/\1/p' file
248
```

but keep it simple and just use awk:

```
$ awk -F'[()]' '/^7,0:/{print $4}' file
248
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep ^590,85: filename | cut -f3 -d'(' | cut -f1 -d')'
```

`grep` selects the line, cut splits the line into columns on the given delimiter (`-d`) and returns the given columns (`-f`).

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed -nE '/^590,85:/ s/.*gray\(([0-9]+)\)/\1/ p' file
```

For lines that begin with `590,85:`, we match the number inside the parenthesis and substitute the complete line with that number, printing it (and suppressing the output for all unmatched lines with `-n`). The extended regexp are enabled with `-E`.

For completeness, if you prefer POSIX basic regex (BRE):

```
sed -n '/^590,85:/ s/.*gray(\([0-9][0-9]*\))/\1/ p' log
```

Note that now we have to escape the grouping parens (and we don't escape the literal parens), also to emulate at-least-one-occurrence operator (`+`), we have to break it into `[0-9]`, followed by zero-or-more occurrence operator over a digit, `[0-9]*`. If using GNU `sed`, you could use `\+` (escaped `+`) instead.

You could also just anchor the match at the end (as suggested by @David in comments), and skip matching of `gray` prefix:

```
sed -n '/^590,85:/ s/.*(\([0-9][0-9]*\))$/\1/ p' log
```

Comment: You can use a BRE without the prematch, e.g. `sed -n 's/^590,85:.*(\([0-9][0-9]*\))$/\1/p'`

Comment: You're right, thanks. I somehow usually default to ERE. But I'll update my answer for completeness. :)

Comment: No big deal, either way works. I just try and stick to BRE as long as there isn't something it won't do, or do without looking like spaghetti, for portability reasons. `sed` was the correct choice, although the OP suggested `grep` and `cut` (which is also correct, it just spawns 3-processes instead of 1).

Comment: IMHO awk is the right choice since it's briefer and clearer than any other solution but you can do this more concisely in sed too, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45317193/1745001.

Comment: @EdMorton, I agree, `awk` solution is the most elegant.

Answer (score 0):

You can `grep` the line you're interested on, and use `grep` again to extract the value:

```
grep '^7,0:' /tmp/filename| grep -Po '\(\K\d+(?=\)$)'
248
```

Comment: can be combined and simplified... `grep -Po '^7,0:.*\(\K\d+'`